# Spotify Web Apps - limit results to 50 instead of the default 100

Tags: xml, spotify

Spotify Web XML/JSON (i'm using XML) makes you default to 100. Is there something I can add to the xml file i'm calling to limit the result to another number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to change the `itemsPerPage` property.

There's no public roadmap for the Web API, but there hasn't been any (significant) changes the past couple of years, so it's not very likely that this will change any time soon.