# Spotify Metadata API : Limit search results

Tags: metadata, spotify

Is there any way to limit the number of records returned in the search artist endpoint of Spotify's metadata api?

Currently, it seems the default is one hundred, and we're only really interested in the first record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered previously; [Spotify Web Apps - limit results to 50 instead of the default 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625438/spotify-web-apps-limit-results-to-50-instead-of-the-default-100). To my knowledge, this has not changed and you are unfortunately still given page with up to 100 results.

However, I'd strongly recommend that you stay tuned for news regarding the Web API in the near future.

**Edit:** We've launched a new version of the Web API, allowing for limiting search results.

Example: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=elvis&type=artist&limit=1

Please check out the [official documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/) for more information.

Comment: @asking: Please check my edited answer. The new Web API can handle this.